# Windows Updates mirror for ISPs

Tags: windows, windows-update, isp, mirror

I work in a ISP where bandwidth is limited. We want to provide our customers a mirror for windows updates, so we can save bandwidth and provide to our customers a faster connection.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: You should contact Microsoft and ask them, they may have something set up for this already.

Comment: Or better yet a CDN that hosts the files like Akamai. They are usually pretty keen on handing out their appliances.

Comment: I cannot emphasize this enough.  You really should contact Microsoft for this type of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to give [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) a try, if you're not using it already.  It's a data-caching application for commonly transferred data.  It may not be able to cache Windows Updates, but it should help you save bandwidth, which seems to be your goal.

http://www.squid-cache.org/Intro/why.html

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky. The only officially sanctioned method for doing this is WSUS, as has been mentioned several times now. In order to use that your clients would have to change their Windows Update data, which can be accomplished by installing the right registry keys but it requires positive action on the part of your clients.

Answer (score 1):

In the Windows world, "mirrors" are typically accomplished utilizing [Windows Server Update Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_Update_Services) (WSUS).  However, you may run into licensing issues if you want to provide that for free as part of your ISP services.

Answer (score 1):

I would install a transparent proxy and cache all downloaded binaries. This would require some sniffing to Windows Update used domains.